# JQuery - dynamic Src image update inside Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following Code, I want to change the Source of a Img Tag present in Dynamically Generated

My Sample div -

```
<div id="content_68608800">
<img id="theImg" src="/static/images/image1.gif"></img>
      Testing
    <a href="/google.com">test</a>
</div>
```

JQuery Javascript Code -

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function(id) {
        var divID= '#content_' + id;
        $(.divID img).attr('src', "/static/images/image2.gif");
        });

id - some Number
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that code. Maybe read how jQuery works.

Comment: `$(.divID img)` shoudl be `$(divID+" img")`, you should have gotten javascript errors in your console due to this.

Comment: Where's `<div class"foo">` - not entirely sure how this code is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click listener, as well as most jQuery functions, receive the event as their parameter.

If you need to get the id via the .foo div you need to pass it otherwise

```
<div class="foo" data-target="#content_68608800"/>
<div id="content_68608800">
    <img id="theImg" src="/static/images/image1.gif"></img>
      Testing
    <a href="/google.com">test</a>
</div>
```

And then in the JS code

```
$(document ).on('click', "div.foo",function() {
    var divID= jQuery(this).data('target');
    $(divID+' img').attr('src', "/static/images/image2.gif");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added content, use jQuery .on():

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(parentElement).on("click", "div.foo", function(){
  ...
});
```